# Tips for determining Joint or Conditional Probability?

Tags: probability

I am studying engineering and one of my mathematics subjects covers some probability and combinatorics, which is something I haven't really touched on in the other mathematics subjects I have done.

The reason I am asking for tips is because I have realised that occasionally I have trouble determining whether probabilities are joint or conditional, and furthermore whether they are co-occurring, independent or mutually exclusive.

In layman's/non jargon terms what do these titles mean?

Also, what are some tips or signs to look for when determining which title category the probability variables fall under?

Comment: I'm having a hard time deciding if this belongs in Engineering.SE or Mathematics.SE.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional probability of $Y$ given $X$ denoted by $P(Y|X)$ is the probability of event $Y$ given that $X$ has already occurred. Joint probability of $X$ and $Y$ denoted by $P(X,Y)$ is the probability of events $X$ and $Y$ happening at the same time. $X$ and $Y$ are independent if $P(X\bigcap Y)=P(X)P(Y)$. $X$ and $Y$ are mutually exclusive if $P(X\bigcap Y)=0$.

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers the part about "in layman's/non jargon terms".

Comment: Ok thanks QuantallicA but that is pretty much exactly what I already have in my maths texts and lectures. So it didn't help too much, but maybe an example could help break it down a little. The problem I am working on is about raining on the weekend. It says if it's 25% chance to rain on Saturday and the same chance on Sunday what is the chance it's going to rain on the weekend? How do I know whether it is joint or conditional probability and what is independent etc.